# Change font size of series label in Google Line Chart

Tags: charts, google-visualization

Is there an option to set the font size for the labels given to each series line, which show up to the right in Google Charts?  In the overview example (https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart) the labels I'm referring to are "Dogs" and "Cats".  My chart has a lot of series, and the labels are too numerous and get cut off at the bottom of the chart. I want to make them smaller so they fit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the following option...

```
legend.textStyle.fontSize
```

e.g.

```
legend: {
  textStyle: {
    fontSize: 8
  }
}
```

Comment: That changes the font size of the title too.  Is there a way to affect only the legend on the right (identifying the series)?  If not, is there a way to shrink the vertical space between them?

Comment: the `titleTextStyle` option controls the title. there is a `chartArea` option, but not specific for spacing between title and legend...

Comment: That helps.  But now it's not working.  What am I missing:  var options = {'height': 500, 'width': 900, legend: {textStyle: {fontSize: 4}}, ...

Comment: Never mind -- I had an extra "legend" option later in the string.  Removed it and it works.  Now the title is the right size, and the right-hand legends work.  Thanks!